# Could a hacker replace a Bitcoin wallet application with a malicious one in some Linux repository?

Tags: security, repository

Bitcoin QT is arguably the most popular Bitcoin wallet application. If a hacker gets access to the data and the private key on some machine, he can steal all the Bitcoins from that wallet.
Being a Linux application, Bitcoin QT is updated regularly when the application in the repository is updated (For example, on `apt-get upgrade` on Debian).

Theoretically, if a hacker could get into some Linux repository, he could replace the application with a malicious one that steals both the private key and the wallet file and send it to a remote server. If possible, even through social engineering, the incentive for such attack is enormous - every Bitcoin is worth well over 1100$ nowadays, and raising rapidly. For example, if the hacker could successfully steal just 10000 bitcoins, he made 10 million USD that probably could never be traced.

My question is - how likely/unlikely that to happen?

[Example for rooted repository incident](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/08/31/linux_kernel_security_breach/)

Comment: The term "repository" is used ambiguously here. The first paragraph seems to refer to package repositories, where [GnuPG is used to sign both individual packages and catalog files](https://wiki.debian.org/SettingUpSignedAptRepositoryWithReprepro), while the link cited seems to suggest the possibility of compromising a source code repository (although in the incident referred to, only a hosting server, _not_ the actual source code repositories were compromised). VCSs like git support [commit signing with GPG](http://driesvints.com/blog/using-a-gpg-key-to-sign-off-git-commits-and-emails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways the attacker can go: inject malicious source code, or inject malicious binaries. If the attacker wants to go the source route, he has to:

1. Inject his malicious source code.
2. Without anyone noticing. (Virtually all open source programs have the change history of their source code on the web.)
3. Without anyone noticing the undue network traffic, loss of bitcoins, etc. due to his malware.

This isn't impossible, but it's pretty difficult. There have been rare attempts to inject code into Linux and other free software. Of course no one has statistics on the undetected attempts, by definition.

If the attacker wants to go the binary route, he has to:

1. Inject his malicious binary.
2. Get people to install it, even though that binary won't have been signed.
3. Without anyone noticing the undue network traffic, loss of bitcoins, etc. due to his malware.

Most Linux distributions provide cryptographically signed packages, which makes #2 tricky. Of course there are people who'll click through the warning anyway, but it means that a breach is guaranteed to be noticed very quickly. There is a way to get around this: if the attacker manages to crack a distribution's build infrastructure, he may get to pass his packages as legitimate.

Note that injecting a malicious bitcoin-related application is not the only way to steal bitcoins. Any other application launched by the user could read the files and attempt to grab the user's password.

An attacker who manages to inject malware on this scale would probably not be after bitcoins. Only a small fraction of the users who installed the malware would have a bitcoin wallet in the first place. The payoff is likely to be bigger selling more generic assets such as credit card information, spam sending, general botnet slots, etc.

See also:

- [Is there way to stop random software packages from remotely transferring your files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101728/is-there-way-to-stop-random-software-packages-from-remotely-transferring-your-fi)
- [Safest way to keep an offline bitcoin wallet](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30731/safest-way-to-keep-an-offline-bitcoin-wallet)
- [How are open-sourced operating systems and software kept secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11271/how-are-open-sourced-operating-systems-and-software-kept-secure)

Comment: "injecting a malicious bitcoin-related application is not the only way to steal bitcoins": this is true, but is set to become false \o/. the systemd people are working on app sandboxing.

Comment: @strugee So inject your malware into the sandbox. Application sandboxing isn't a panacea and is very very hard to do for the desktop (though [some people are working on it](http://qubes-os.org/)) if you want to retain things like inter-application copy-paste, window manager macro facilities, etc.

Comment: the idea is that copy and paste, window manager control, etc. happen through D-Bus. see http://youtu.be/_rrpjYD373A?t=38m17s. my point was that if e.g. Firefox is properly sandboxed to `~/.mozilla`, then it wouldn't be able to read your Bitcoin data.

Comment: @strugee You still need a pretty big [trusted base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_base). And if FF is sandboxed to `~/.mozilla`, you can't e.g. download or upload files on websites without needing to also use a file manager (part of the trusted base) to move them.

Comment: the way downloads and uploads are implemented is that Firefox asks GTK+ for a file dialog, and then receives (or sends) the file over D-Bus. this is why Kernel D-Bus is important: it makes that feasible by reducing overhead.

Comment: @strugee In that case FF can upload your Bitcoin wallet. There's no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11773/discussion-between-strugee-and-gilles)